# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble._gb_losses'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

i have install the scikit_learn and tried to install multiple version but not able to download

not able to find answer for **sklearn.ensemble._gb_losses**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle
import numpy as np

model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb"))
app = Flask(__name__)
Model = pickle.load(model)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict_crop():
    n = float(request.form.get('Nitrogen'))
    p = float(request.form.get('Phosphorus'))
    k = float(request.form.get('Potassium'))
    r = float(request.form.get('Rainfall'))

    # predict
    result = model.predict(np.array([n, p, k, r]).reshape(1, 4))
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is my code i have added the pkl file

```
model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb"))
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**ModuleNotFoundError:**

> No module named
> 'sklearn.ensemble._gb_losses'

i think its mostly with the problem with versioning of library or it could be the problem with my model

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with scikit_learn earlier, and solved it by downgrading to 1.3.2:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn==1.3.2
```

Or use conda if you prefer ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).